# Does Kotlin 1.4 drop support for Coroutine Actors

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've upgraded my Android project to use `ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0"` and I cannot import Coroutine `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.actor`.

I know Actors were marked as obsolete

```
 * **Note: This API will become obsolete in future updates with introduction of complex actors.**
 *           See [issue #87](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/87).
 *
```

Did I miss the announcement that Actors have been removed?

How do I obtain complex actors?

I couldn't find any mention of actors in the changelog

my gradle resembles this:-

```
api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```